# Get main picture URL of LinkedIn user

Tags: linkedin-api

When requesting [Basic Profile Fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) for a specific user we get back the following:

1. `picture-url`, a URL for a square profile picture with a size of
   100x100 pixels.
2. `picture-urls`, a list containing URLs for the original uploaded
   picture.

What I need is the user's picture in square size **and** in a higher quality.

I know that the user's main picture (the one that is available on his/her profile page under `https://www.linkedin.com/in/[user_id]/`) is the size of 200x200 pixels, which is much better.

How can I access this picture URL through the API?

*Remark:* If I try to just generate this URL I get *Access Denied* error.

Comment: It doesn't appear that the LinkedIn API supports any other formats. You'll probably need to use the original quality version provided and crop/resize it yourself.

Comment: Thanks [John Ellmore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5651536/john-ellmore), but that's a solution I thought of before. It seems so far that the answer is just no, it's not possible...

Comment: So the answer to this question is that - No you can not access the high resolution picture URL using LinkedIn's API ?

Comment: [Rann Lifshitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5321363/rann-lifshitz) Please see my last reply to [Christos Lytras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889685/christos-lytras).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LinkedIn API does not have any documented way to access the different sizes of the generated images. You can use `picture-urls::(original)` field to get the original uploaded picture URL and then scale it as you like. The original uploaded image can be even larger than 200x200 that the LinkedIn profile uses.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile

> **picture-urls::(original)** *A URL to the member's original unformatted
>   profile picture.  This image is usually larger than the picture-url
>   value above.*

**API Call**

```
GET: /v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,picture-urls::(original))
```

**Result**

```
{
    "firstName": "Christos",
    "id": "...",
    "lastName": "Litras",
    "pictureUrl": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQHcTGe3GOQviw/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0?e=1528894800&v=beta&t=JzgIhDOm-xGxIEuQP1jy3sFHRAeN5pk5skHhXm9s3wM",
    "pictureUrls": {
        "_total": 1,
        "values": [
            "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5600AQG-fzvmQVCLsg/profile-originalphoto-shrink_900_1200/0?e=1528894800&v=beta&t=TrtntJgtAHeolrPeteffiq_Ixg-JecaAvutQioy0c8A"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks [Christos Lytras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889685/christos-lytras), but that's a solution I thought of before. It seems so far that the answer is just no, it's not possible...

Comment: What's far? You get the URL with the original uploaded image that you can then downscale as you like, even with CSS or with some image rendering functions.

Comment: What I meant is that, so far/currently, it seems that there's no way to access the URL to *"the user's picture in square size **and** in a higher quality"*, which is provided on the user' profile page, through the API.
As for working with the original image, this was a solution which my team and I already discussed about (using cropping or CSS), but we prefer **not** to do so as this require some server-side work (doing crop) or client-side work (doing CSS, which, unfortunately, means for us, changing the CSS in a lot of places) instead of just fetching a different URL.

Comment: @Ofir you can create a simple server script (in PHP it's no more that 5-7 lines of code) that crops the image and then use that scripts URL to replace the image URL. The LinkedIn API does not have any documented way to access the different sizes of the generated images.

Comment: [Christos Lytras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889685/christos-lytras) Please add this last sentence of yours (_"The LinkedIn API does not have..."_) to your original answer and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Ofir just edited my answer and added that sentence.